# Asynchronous delegates operation clarification?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0

*I was reading [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172773/net-threadpool-worker-threads-and-asynchronous-io-threads) and answer by Hans but still I need a clarification.*

AFAIK ,

> The purpose of asynchronous **methods** is to allow many tasks to run on
>   few threads; while the purpose of asynchronous **delegates** is to execute a
>   task in parallel with the caller.

But regarding both asynchronous operations:

If the `BeginInvoke` returns *immediately* to the caller (*and it does with Asynchronous delegate*) , so there must be  other thread which actually do the job and  signal when it finished.

So what is the difference between using *that* thread to a regular threadpool thread ?
And I answer : only the fact that those threadpool threads are already there and waiting to be run ?

But what about the fact that when `BeginInvoke` run and returned immediatly , someone *else* has actually do the dirty job ( and a code must be run under a thread which is under process.) so *there must be* somewhere a creation of thread (which run after beginXXX call)

What am I missing?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961450/where-are-clr-defined-methods-like-delegate-begininvoke-documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Delegate.BeginInvoke` uses a threadpool thread, just like `QueueUserWorkItem`. The difference is that it implements the APM pattern, which allows the caller to use a `WaitHandle` to wait for the call to finish, and also supply a callback.

The Begin/End method pair (AKA the Asynchronous Programming Model) can be found in many places, and it is entirely up to the implementer to decide what happens when you call 'begin'. In many cases, a IO completion port is used, which is a very efficient way for waiting for IO to complete. When IO completes, a threadpool thread is used to execute the callback, but it is taken from a different part of the threadpool (and that's why Set{Min,Max}Threads have two numbers.)

As a side note, with .NET 4.5 (and even 4.0) it is far easier to use Tasks for asynchrony. Many classes have been augmented with methods like 'XXXTaskAsyc' which return a `Task` object.

Comment: Eli : you said _When IO completes s, a threadpool thread is used to execute the callback_ but lets take one step back , **before it** completes and still working , is it working under a threadpool thread ?

Comment: Eli so that is my actual question. Im yielding the work the an OS thread. so it is a creation of thread. so where is the benefit? just that it aint a threapool thread?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you already got the answer yourself: `BeginInvoke` uses a `Threadpool`-thread to do the work. In the end, it appears to be not any different from queueing a work-item to the threadpool yourself. The only things is that is a higher level of abstraction you are facing. You are not actually concerned with queueing and providing a callback explicitly in your code.
This has already been looked at. See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772597/difference-between-delegate-begininvoke-and-thread-start) here for an idea.

Comment: _fetching a web page, for instance, might take up
to several seconds from start to end (because of a potentially slow connection) and
yet consume only a fraction of a millisecond of CPU time in total. Processing an
HTTP request and response is not computationally intensive.
This means that a server thread dedicated to processing a single client request might
spend 99% of its time blocked_. **SO** are you telling me that still there will be a threadpool (thread) which is blocked 99% of time ?

Comment: Why the entire threadpool? Of course a thread will block, if it waits for data or anything else. That doesn't block the entire threadpool, though.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Okay, but still that is the nature of a thread waiting for input. And if it is meant to be blocked for a certain amount of time, than that will happen.

Comment: @EliArbel these are special cases, of course. But if you do it the standard way, the thread will block.